# Cucumber feature file name is Jira ticket number

Tags: java, test-automation-framework, cucumber

I am starting to name my cucumber `.feature` files as `VerifyLogin_JIRA-1211.feature`

Is this the correct/optimum naming convention?

This question might get closed due to "opinion-based" but there is no place else, where I can ask questions about standard coding conventions.

Still, if it's not worth asking here, maybe direct me to some forums which have good naming conventions.

Comment: It's just a file name, Cucumber doesn't even take into consideration. If you and your team like it, go on. If you realize you don't, you can rename all at once with a simple regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think feature files names should describe the functionality. [The Cucumber Book](https://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) uses `user_logs_in.feature` as a name for their first example. This gives the following domain information: The system has users and there is a login function.

If I open a folder with feature files I like it best if it gives me a general idea what the application does, e.g. what its features are. Having file names with words like Verify and Jira_Codes makes me feel you are using Cucumber as a testing tool and not a collaboration tool. It makes reading the names of the files more complex and does not really assist with understanding the domain.

I do understand the wish for traceability. I do not think one feature file maps to only one Jira-ticket or Specs-document. I started adding tags to features files to link them, for example, `@SPECDOC-1211` and `@TFS-123456` work items.

As I am writing this I think I would prefer to just add the traceability to the feature free text block. You can search for it, which seems good enough.

```
user_logs_in.feature
Feature: User logs in
    As a User,
    I want to be able to log in to the system,
    So that I can use its valuable features

    Implemented in JIRA-1211, JIRA-1231

Scenario: Valid credentials
Scenario: Registration
```

Reads:

- https://cucumber.io/blog/collaboration/the-worlds-most-misunderstood-collaboration-tool/

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends.

It is **correct** if it suits you and your team. And about being **optimal** also depends on the way you are structuring your tests.

If the workflow depends on a JIRA story, your example seems fitting and also provides traceability to JIRA issues.

In my previous workplace, I used to name the feature files according to functional specification's chapters and it worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely this question is opinion based. Recently I'm working on a project where client require the same way as you are asking to create our feature files. each feature file should have the Jira Ticket id along with the title.

e.g. `AXMA-9204_Verify_x_functionality_working_fine_on_y_page.feature`

And what i think is, Its very easy get the high level details about the particular scenario from project explorer itself without opening that file and read the description.